# Is there any control not derived from dependency object in WPF?

Tags: wpf

Someone asked this question which i don't have answer

**Is there any control not derived from dependency object in WPF?**

Answer (score 1):

The literal answer to your question is no.

That's because Control is a class which inherits from Dependency Object.

See the inheritance chain here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.control?view=netframework-4.7.2

Object - DispatcherObject - DependencyObject - VisualUIElement - FrameworkElement - Control

Comment: Yes. That's my understanding as well but some one asked me this question in interview and claiming there is one control and WPF people have done it purposefully.

Comment: @Gopu That's impossible. All WPF controls must be UIElements (or Visuals), otherwise they won't be rendered. Probably ask the interviewer if they were making fun of you. Or what they are talking about after all.

Comment: Difficult to even guess what he might have in mind. It cannot be a control.